# Finding the right pattern to match a group of characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, match

I am searching for the right pattern in order to match a string, which may contain only the following characters:

```
a-z
A-z
0-9
```

and these in addition:

```
@!#$&'()+-,./[]_~
```

i tried this php code:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@\!#\$&\'\(\)\+,\-\./\[\]_~]{0,255}$/', $path)
```

I is going to be used for paths. I want to allow only these characters before creating any directories on the filesystem.

But no matter how i am changing the pattern, it wont match normal paths like

```
/bin/bash
/home/user
```

what should be changed it order to make it work?

Comment: Are those valid characters for paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the forward slash as the delimiter, you need to escape it:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@\!#\$&\'\(\)\+,\-\.\/\[\]_~]{0,255}$/', $path)
                                            ^^ here
```

Comment: I knew it ... something very litte. Thank you !! :-)